# AccessControlException on template loading in shared tomcat hosting environment

Tags: spring, freemarker

My application is deployed in a shared Tomcat hosting environment where my appBase is outside of the container and the security policy is strictly maintained. I am now trying to introduce Freemarker templating, but am getting this:

```
Could not create a file template loader for current directory
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\apache-tomcat\bin read)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:731)
        at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$1.run(FileTemplateLoader.java:124)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:122)
        at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:108)
        at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:94)
        at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.createDefaultTemplateLoader(TemplateCache.java:120)
        at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.<init>(TemplateCache.java:115)
        at freemarker.template.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:110)
        at freemarker.template.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:96)
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.newConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:266)
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.java:6
0)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1504)
```

even though I believe the security policy recommendations for Freemarker have been followed.

Using Spring to inject the Configuration:

```
<bean id="freemarkerMailConfiguration"
        class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">

    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="file:/C:/apache-tomcat-files/mailtemplates/"/>
</bean>
```

or manually creating it

```
    Configuration freemarkerMailConfiguration = new Configuration();
    File dir = new File("C:/apache-tomcat-files/mailtemplates");
    freemarkerMailConfiguration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(dir);
```

the exception seems to originate with the no-args constructor of Configuration, where presumably it tries to load from the default location before you can get to change it - using setDirectoryForTemplateLoading() is too late.

Can anyone tell me whether I can successfully set the directory when the default is out of bounds?

Many thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a Warning in the log (not an Error), don't worry about it. What goes on is that when you do `new Configuration()`, it tries to set up the default `TemplateLoader` that loads from the *current directory*, that's in you case happens to be `C:\apache-tomcat\bin`. When it fails, it logs this, then uses `null` as `TemplateLoader`. It doesn't mater, since you set the `TemplateLoader` yourself anyway, so you override its default value.

(BTW, with 2.3.21 if you use `new Configuration(new Version(2, 3, 21))` then this warning is avoided, as it doesn't use that silly default for the `TemplateLoader` anymore.)